# Can Asymptote project 2D images in 3D?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote, technical-drawing

The pst-solides3d package can project 2D .eps images into a plane in 3D. From the documentation:

[image]

Can Asymptote project a 2D .eps into planes embedded in 3D? Asymptote can import 2D images into a 2D picture with

```
label(graphic("file"),(0,0));
```

but I can't find any examples in 3D.

Comment: Perspective projection or orthonormal projection? The former, as far as I know, does not exist.

Comment: Perspective projection would be great, but orthonormal (orthographic?) would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. As you point out, Asymptote's mechanism for importing images uses labels. In 3d, labels are rendered as surfaces; the shape of the label is extracted, but any coloration is ignored. I'm guessing any image you attempted to draw this way would show up as a black parallelogram.

Comment: This is quite annoying, and possibly the biggest lacuna in Asymptote for me right now... I often would like to draw atop a 2D graphic with 3D arrows. Is there no way to interpret a WxH image as a lattice of colored squares, short of drawing WxH individual squares? Would work both in 2D and 3D, but would generate millions of draw commands, vertices, edges.... and would be hideously large as vector graphics and slow to render.