# Can PSTricks display a .eps file generated from a bitmap?

Tags: graphics, pstricks, asymptote

PSTricks can project .eps images onto 2D planes in 3D. Here's an example from the documentation.

[image]

I would like to perform a similar projection with a bitmap image (.png or .jpg). I've tried converted the bitmap to .eps using ImageMagick, but PSTricks doesn't work with the .eps output from ImageMagick.

Has anyone displayed a bitmap in PSTricks?

Parallel question here: [Can Asymptote project 2D images in 3D?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351589/can-asymptote-project-2d-images-in-3d)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this works. Here is an example. Of course you need to come up with your eps files. I created those used in the example below with ImageMagick.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage{pst-all}
 \usepackage{pst-3dplot,pst-blur}
 \usepackage{graphicx} % including PostScript
 \newcommand{\CenterObject}[1]{\ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}}}

 \begin{document}

  \newgray{gray75}{0.75}\newgray{gray85}{0.85}\newgray{gray95}{0.95}
  \begin{pspicture}(-5.5,-2.5)(5,3.5)
   \psset{viewpoint=1 1.5 0.5}
   \ThreeDput(0,0,0){$\CenterObject{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Galaxie.eps}}$}
   \psset{viewpoint=-1 -1.5 0.5}
   \ThreeDput(-4.5,-4.5,0){\Huge \white 4D space--time}
   \psset{viewpoint=1 1.5 0.5}
    \ThreeDput(2,2,0){\psellipse*[linecolor=gray75](0.02,0.01)}
      \pspolygon[fillcolor=gray75,fillstyle=solid,linecolor=gray75](-0.58,-0.75)(-3.48,1.5)(2.39,1.52)(-0.58,-0.75)
   \ThreeDput(2,2,2.5){\psellipse[fillcolor=white,linecolor=gray75,fillstyle=solid](3,3)}
   \ThreeDput[normal=0 1 0](2,2,2.75){\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{calabi-yau-space-small.eps}}
    \rput[c](-4,2.6){\ovalnode[shadow=true,blur=true]{cal}{\begin{tabular}{c}
    compact\\ space
    \end{tabular}}}
    \pnode(-1,2.3){cal1}
    \ncarc{->}{cal}{cal1}
  \end{pspicture}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm I tried your snippet with my .eps files (and .png files) and I got a garbled image. How did you create the .eps file? Just `convert input.png output.eps`?

Comment: @Talon Chandler: Yes, I used convert. Did you ever view your eps file without including it in a PSTricks picture? (Notice also that I do not use pdflatex, rather I compile to ps and then convert the ps to eps and then to pdf.)

Comment: Excellent that works perfectly. As you guessed, I had an issue in my conversion chain.